# How to integrate PayPal button into Extjs environment?

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

While there is a number of tutorials on Paypal Payment Integration, there is no one dealing wit EXTJS framework.
Integration of PayPal button is pretty straightforward in index.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Add meta tags for mobile and IE -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title> PayPal Smart Payment Buttons Integration | Horizontal Buttons </title>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Set up a container element for the button -->
    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

    <!-- Include the PayPal JavaScript SDK -->
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=USD"></script>

    <script>
        // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
        paypal.Buttons({
            style: {
                layout: 'horizontal'
            }
        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

But, how to include it in EXTJS? I do not understand how to mix extjs MVC or MVVM architecture with plain javascipt and html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the html part in a container and put the buttons code in the after render event

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.mypanel',


    title: 'Main Panel',
    height:400,

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            width: 200,
            border: true,
            height: 400,
            html:'<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>',
            listeners:{
            
                afterrender: function (){
                      paypal.Buttons({
                  
                     }).render('#paypal-button-container');
                
                }
            }
        },
    ],

});


Ext.application({
    views: [
        'MyPanel'
    ],
    name: 'MyApp',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('MyApp.view.MyPanel', {renderTo: Ext.getBody()});
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ext.js has an index.html file. You can add the script tag loading the PayPal there. I.e. you need to add these lines to your index.html

```
 <!-- Include the PayPal JavaScript SDK -->
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=USD"></script>
```

Then create some sort of container (e.g. an Ext.Panel) set the placholder div as the value of the html property then you can use the paypal code to render into this div. E.g.

```js
     Ext.define('Paypal', {
        extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
        html: '<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>',

        onRender() {
            this.callParent();
            // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
            paypal.Buttons({
                style: {
                    layout: 'horizontal'
                }
            }).render('#paypal-button-container');
        }
    });

    Ext.application({
        name: 'Paypal',
        launch: function () {
            Ext.create('Paypal', {
                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align: 'stretch'
                },
                width: 300,
                height: 200,
                renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            })
        }
    });
```

Working example can be found [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/3c5k)

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me why this isn't working with classic toolkit? I changed  'Ext.Panel' to 'Ext.panel.Panel'.

Comment: Updated my ansver and the linked fiddle to work with classic toolkit.